# How can I kill a program started from rc.local when Ctrl-C doesn't work?

Tags: startup, kill, rc

I was trying to create a program that runs at start-up that takes a picture every 10 seconds (In a infinite loop) on my raspberry pi but I discovered I had made a mistake but couldn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of it. Is there a way to escape?

(I did try to go to a different workspace but login prompt wouldn't show.)

Comment: Hmm, you could try sending a `SIGQUIT` which is a control-plus-backslash by default (`stty -a | grep quit`). Otherwise, did SSH start before `rc.local` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you start the program from rc.local, then you cannot login to a shell and type ctrl-c to stop it.  The reason is that the program was not started from the shell that you're logged into.

You will find the process ID (`pid`) of the program and use the `kill` command to send the process a signal, causing it to terminate.

For example, at a console (in a terminal window or logged in via ssh):

```
ps aux | grep 'the-name-of-your-progam'
```

The number in the second column is the `pid`.  Use that `pid` to send the process a termination signal:

```
kill -TERM [put-your-pid-here]
```

A process may choose to ignore the `TERM` signal, so run the `ps` pipeline again.  If you still see the same `pid`, then send the kill signal:

```
kill -KILL [put-your-pid-here]
```

Comment: how is the guy supposed to input a terminal command when he doesn't have a terminal??

Comment: @johnktejik, the guy can login remotely via ssh, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @RobertL Can't login via ssh either

Comment: Okay check your ip b/c I was using 191.168.1.? instead of 192....  Future readers